# Insert list of records using mybatis

Tags: mybatis, h2db

I am trying to insert records into a table from a list using Mybatis. I use mybatis velocity as scripting language. Looks like the problem is in the parameter symbol #. I tried to replace that with @ since I'm using mybatis velocity but nothing worked. Could someone please help me out.

Mapper.java:

```
void insertFileVersions(@Param("versionsList") List<Integer> activeFileVersions);
```

mapper.xml:

```
<insert id="insertFileVersions" parameterType="java.util.List">
<foreach collection="versionsList" item="version" index="index">
    INSERT INTO FILE_TEMP (FILE_ID, FILE_VERSION) VALUES (#{version.fileId}, #
{version.fileVersion})
</foreach>
</insert>
```

I get the error Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "VERSION.FILEID" not found; SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all wrong for Velocity - you are using the XML language driver syntax.  With the  Velocity language driver, you use `@{...}` instead of `#{...}`, and you also use `#repeat` instead of `<foreach>`.  See this page for some examples: http://www.mybatis.org/velocity-scripting/

But please consider writing your code differently and using MyBatis' batch capabilities, rather then generating one giant statement.  See this FAQ for an example: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix this using #repeat.